# reference not working as expected in try catch

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {
    int a = 20;
    cout<<"address of a is "<<&a<<endl;
    try{
        throw a;
    }
    catch (int& z) {
            cout<<"address of z is "<<&z<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The address of `a` is not same as that of `z`. It means reference doesn't work in try catch. If not then why compiler is not generating any error? And what does above code mean?

Comment: **a** is copied when you _throw_ it.

Comment: @Adriano It means references lose their meaning as used in above case?

Comment: I guess this is just an example (so I won't ask why you catch a reference of an int). References don't lose their meaning but when you _use_ a _value type_ (as our .NET friends would call them) you'll pass to _throw_ a copy of the original value.

Comment: @Adriano Yes above one is example. But practical application is when you want to throw class object which is exceeding the parameter size, then I thought of passing reference. So how to tackle this big size parameter passing as in this case(because reference is not working)?

Comment: I posted an answer. You can't for that reason (and it's a very good reason!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess my comment was not so clear so I write something as answer.

When you throw that exception you throw it **by value**. It means that it'll be copied (it doesn't matter if it's a primitive type or a copied object). Of course when an object is copied then its memory location changes (it's a **new** object). Why this? Because exceptions can unroll the stack to find a proper catch block. If you throw something by reference what you **may** get is garbage (because when a variable goes out of scope it'll be destroyed). I said **may** because in reality the compiler does not allow to throw a reference and you'll always have a copy.

If your exception object is really big you may consider to allocate the object with new and then throw its pointer. But *someone* has to deallocate it. Are you ready for the risk? Take a look (as example) at the `CException` implementation on MFC and its [Delete()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97z4sxfb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method (they try to make this easy but I'm not really happy of that).

Maybe you wonder **why** if you have to throw by value you catch by reference. First because it's how `std::exception` is designed to be used (try to call the `what()` method of an exception catched *by value*). Second because it lets the compiler to perform some optimizations (moreover, even if you do not use std::exception, you won't create useless copies of that object).

Answer (score 3):

When you throw an object of any type, the Standard allows compilers to make copy of the object as many times as it wishes. Therefore, in the `catch` block, you might not get the original object you threw, and instead it can be a different object, which is  a *copy* of the original object, or a copy of the copy of the copy of the original object, or so on.